# Google play console action required to update server side billing confirmation API, but API is already using latest version

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

We received this error in our Google play console recently:

```
ACTION REQUIRED: Your server-side billing confirmations will stop working on December 1, 2019
Your app is using an old version of the Google Play Developer API. From December 1 2019, versions 1 and 2 of this API will no longer be available, and any calls to these versions will fail. Update to version 3 before this date. Note that this is not related to the AIDL/Billing Library deprecation. Learn more
```

However, we are currently using the correct API version3 in our server to validate our in app purchase billing receipts. An in app purchase library we're using also exposes the functionality in client side, and I've confirmed their source code is also making use of v3. Both are calling request to `https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/...`

We've had real purchases be validated in production so I know it's functional and I'm trying to understand where the source of problem is.

I also read [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/03/changes-to-google-play-developer-api.html) that it might be due to third party plugins.

If anything we've recently integrated Facebook SDK which said it could do android receipt validation for us to make sure it's not reporting any fraud/sandbox purchases.

Has anyone else encountered this action required sign? If so, what steps did you take to eliminate/resolve it, and were they related to third party plugins that were using the androidpublisher apis?

Comment: I too am running into this! I am 100% certain it's due to the Facebook SDK because the warning showed up after I enabled purchase authentication by providing Google Play credentials in the Facebook app settings. It looks like they need to update their code. Any idea what we can do to make this happen? I see a lot of invalid purchases which would not be detected without this working.

Comment: we have this problem too, but v3 is used.

Comment: @Flyview, what is the facebook SDK version you're using? I'm on 5.0.3, and the latest is 5.11 so I'm wondering if the sdk just needs to be updated.

Comment: @Rachel that could be it, I'm on 5.2.0 (from around August?). They've had since May to change it but perhaps they finally did recently. Even if we update it now, most people will not get the update by December 1st, and I don't suppose the warning will go away until all calls to the old API end?

Comment: Thanks for posting this! We are also seeing this error in the console and also use v3 of the API. Good catch with the facebook SDK, that must be our issue as well. We're on 5.6

Answer (score 2):

Might be you are using

**https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1/applications/**

For validating purchase replace **V1** with **V3**

**https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get**

for validating  purchase receipt from server side.

Comment: yes google stop supporting v1 validation so replace with v3 version .

Comment: You can't just replace it when it's a third party library (facebook sdk) still using the old version.